# Embedding Python in VC++/MFC application

Tags: python, visual-c++

Is it possible to embed Python in a `VC++/MFC` application. If yes, can you please tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can embed python in any application where you can call functions from a C library. The fact that you are using MFC is not really important for this.

The official python documentation for this is pretty good:

- http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html
- http://docs.python.org/c-api/index.html

On how to do that: basically you simply call `Py_Initialize();` to initialize Python and then do whatever you want to do with it. Before your application exits it's a good idea to call `Py_Finalize();` to clean up things.