# How to embed python enviroment and use it in MFC appliication?

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I want to embed python script and a minimal python environment in MFC application.

So my questions are:

1. How to embed a minial python enviroment within my application?
2. How to choose the python environment in my application? Because use may have their own python installations, I need to let my application the one installed by my application.

Comment: I implemented (CPython) Python in a big application, and I highly recommend not to rely on a system installation of Python, ship your own Python version. Does this solve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062333/embedding-python-in-vc-mfc-application

Comment: @HelloWorld I have read that topic previously, it didn't mention how to choose the specific python location (in my case the minimal python environment installed with my application).

Comment: Before you initialize Python, use `Py_SetPythonHome` with the path to the virtualenv you want to use. Looking at my code, Seems I also use `Py_SetProgramName` with the location of `python.exe` in the specific virtualenv, although I don't recall why that was necessary.

Comment: @user1633272 You need to load the library first, e.g. on Windows for example with `LoadLibraryW`. You must decide on your own how to select the library first. E.g. Visual Studio Code just lists all Python installations and lets the user decide. Although this is not embedded in VScode, it should bring you a step closer https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter

Comment: @DanMašek I guess because some code relies on `sys.executable`, maybe that?

Comment: @HelloWorld Yeah, quite likely. The scripts use matplotlib and jinja and then run latex to typeset the result to PDF. Just not sure what it was exactly, it's been years since I wrote the code.

Comment: @HelloWorld I don't think OP needs to worry about loading the library -- boost-python will already be tied to the version of Python it was built against, so there's really no choice in that. The only choice is the location of the python environment, so the program doesn't need to rely on a system installation.

Comment: @DanMašek Yes, I’m confused, which library should I load? The library containing Py_xxx?

Comment: From my experience none -- the application is linked with boost-python and to the python library (same one that boost-python is linked with), which means the system loads the DDLs for you on application start. On startup, I call the 2 functions I mentioned earlier to make it use the venv, then I call `Py_Initialize`, then I call init functions of the `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE`s defined in my app, and that's it.

Comment: I didn't see the boost tag, thanks for the clarification

Comment: @DanMašek `Py_SetPythonHome` works.